# Замена нескольких строк в файле python

Tags: python

Есть toml-файл, который имеет примерно следующее содержимое:

```
service-1='v.0.3.63'
service-2='v.0.3.72'
service-3='v.1.2.0'
```

Я хочу заменить содержимое этого файла на следующее

```
SERVICE_1_VER='v.0.3.63'
SERVICE_2_VER='v.0.3.72'
SERVICE_3_VER='v.1.2.0'
```

я могу это сделать, но максимально тупым способом, открывая каждый раз файл и записывая туда новые данные на основе старых

```
import re

with open ("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    new_data = old_data.upper()
with open ("test.toml", 'w') as f:
   f.write(new_data)

with open ("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    new_data = re.sub(r"'V.", r"'v.", old_data) 
with open ("test.toml", 'w') as f:
   f.write(new_data)

with open ("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    new_data = re.sub(r"-", r"_", old_data)  
with open ("test.toml", 'w') as f:
   f.write(new_data)

with open ("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    new_data = re.sub(r"='", r"_VER='", old_data)   
with open ("test.toml", 'w') as f:
   f.write(new_data)
```

но кажется это максимально тупо, я хочу открыть файл, заменить все сразу и закрыть файл, но знаний не хватает(

если делаю цикл типа такого:

```
with open ("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    for new_data in "test.toml":
        new_data = old_data.upper()
        new_data = re.sub(r"'V.", r"'v.", old_data) 
        new_data = re.sub(r"-", r"_", old_data) 
        new_data = re.sub(r"='", r"_VER='", old_data)  
with open ("test.toml", 'w') as f:
   f.write(new_data)
```

то получаю только последнее изменение `re.sub(r"='", r"_VER='", old_data)` (что вполне логично)

помогите, пожалуйста, сделать нормальный цикл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть-чуть не дожали. Вам надо было читать по строкам, изменять их, и складывать новые в список для записи в файл.

```
import re

new_data = []
with open("test.toml", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_line = line.upper()
        new_line = re.sub(r"'V.", r"'v.", new_line)
        new_line = re.sub(r"-", r"_", new_line)
        new_line = re.sub(r"='", r"_VER='", new_line)
        new_data.append(new_line)

with open("new_test.toml", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_data)
```

Comment: точно!
спасибо большое)